# 2-Dimensional array deallocation

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, pointers, multidimensional-array

As an intro, I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2010, compiling for x64. I have a program that's using 2-Dimensional arrays to store data for running through a C style function that I have no control over:

```
float **results;
results = new float*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
    results[i] = new float[columns];
}

int **data;
data = new int*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
    data[i] = new int[columns];
}

//send data to the function and populate results with values
ExternalFunction(*data, *results);

//delete everything
for (int i = 0; i < rows-1; ++i){
    delete [] &results[i];
    delete [] &data[i];
}
delete [] results;
delete [] data;
```

This causes VS10 to through a Debug Assertion Failure with _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse). This happens by the end of the program regardless of what really happens in the last few lines containing the deletes. What does this mean exactly? What am I doing wrong? I feel like it's really simple, but I've been looking at this code for too long.

--EDIT---
Problem solved thanks to dasblinkenlight's helpful nudge to my brain!

```
float *results = new float[rows * columns];
float *data = new float[rows * columns];

ExternalFunction(&data[0], &results[0]);

delete [] results;
delete [] data;
```

Comment: This line `ExternalFunction(*data, *results)` looks suspicious: if the function takes 2D arrays, it should be `ExternalFunction(data, results)`. These lines `delete [] &results[i];` also look wrong: they should be `delete [] results[i];`

Comment: Why do you delete one less row than you've initialized?

Comment: The external function requires a pointer to a data set stored in row major order, typical C fashion. Maybe I'm doing that wrong? But I don't think so.

Comment: @user850275 `*data` is one-dimensional array, not a matrix in row major order. Same goes for `*results` - it's the same as `results[0]`.

Comment: Though, dasblinkenlight just got me thinking. I may have found out what I'm doing wrong. The above code does not make a C style matrix. A matrix like that would have to be a contiguous list, then I would pass the first element of that list to the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code crashes because you are passing an address of an address to `delete[]`, which is not what you allocated. Change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows ; ++i){
    delete [] results[i];
    delete [] data[i];
}
```

It will no longer crash.

The rule on this is simple: since you assigned the results of `new[..]` to `results[i]`, you should be passing `results[i]`, not `&results[i]`, to `delete []`. Same goes for `data`.

Also note that this code deletes all rows that you allocated, including the last one (the loop condition is now `i < n`, not `i < n-1`). Thanks bjhend!

Answer (score 0):

You could use below as a macro or some delete function for 2D array with row count predefined :

```
for_each(results, results + rows , [](int* row) { delete[] row; });
delete[] results;
```