# Proper way of deleting a char** array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I have a dynamically allocated `char**` array as a private member in one of my classes.

The first allocation occurs according to number of words

```
client_interests = new char* [n];
```

Later each index of the array is allocated according to length of the word + 1

```
char[i] = new char [strlen(word)+1];
```

Would this be the proper way of deallocating the memory of this member (the classes dtor is calling this function)?

```
void Client::deallocate()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) //loops through each word
    {
        delete [] client_interests[i]; //each word is an array of characters, hence delete [] is used
    }
    delete [] client_interests; //deallocating the pointer
    client_interests = NULL;
}
```

Thaks!

Comment: Honestly, using a `std::vector<std::string>` would be the most "proper" way of dealing with this outright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2-Dimensional array deallocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220322/2-dimensional-array-deallocation)

Comment: Yes, I know - but this is the assignment that was given to us, we have to use c type strings.

Comment: Your code seems not to have any errors, although `std::vector<std::string>` is much much **much far** better solution.

Comment: You want to check whether `client_interests` is null before the loop; otherwise, calling the function a second time will do bad things with a null pointer. (Alternatively, do this work directly in the destructor, so there's no danger of calling it twice). Also, make sure you're following the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) (which standard containers would give you automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Since you allocate using `new []`, de-allocating with `delete []` as you do is required. Also, obviously de-allocating in reverse order - inner arrays first, then outer array - is also required.

Comment: How about `for (i = n-1; i >= 0; --i)` if you *really* want reverse order? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow If you like, but it's not necessary and maybe not as readable. The reverse order need only apply to outer/inner, not to the individual inner allocations themselves, as they are independent. That said, if there are additional semantics and exception-safety concerns, it may be appropriate to do as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you absolutely cannot use `std::vector<std::string>`, then your way of deallocating things is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the correct way of deallocating the 2d array.

```
delete []
```

is used to deallocate an array, and you are doing it correctly as you first deallocate the inner arrays and than the outer array.